# How can I create and return a cursor from a plsql function?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I created a plsql function and I want to create a cursor and return this cursor from the function. Then I want to call this function in a Java class and retrieve data from the cursor. Note: the cursor returns one row.
I wrote something like this,,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION FUNCTION1 ( emp_id IN NUMBER)RETURN cursor AS

  cursor newCursor(e_id number) is  
    select * from table1 where employee_id = e_id;        
    type refCursor is ref cursor;

  BEGIN

  open newCursor(emp_id);    
  loop
  exit when newCursor%notfound;   
    fetch newCursor into refCursor;  
  end loop;
  RETURN refCursor;

END FUNCTION1;
```

What return type should I use if I want to return a cursor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Model it after the following function which works

```
create or replace function getemps return sys_refcursor is
v_curs sys_refcursor;
begin
open v_curs for select ename from emp;
return v_curs;
end;
/
```

Comment: if I want to pass parameter to the cursor in this case, how can I do that??

Comment: how to do in a package?

Answer (score 0):

sys_refcursor is oracle's generic implicit cursor
use EXPLICITE cursor instead